# Getting descriptive login error messages in iOS app using AWS Cognito

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am developing an iOS app in Swift using AWS Cognito to handle user login and registration. I've found that when users do something that Cognito doesn't allow (entering the wrong username/password on login, trying to create a password that doesn't match the requirements, etc.) the app will display error messages such as`The operation couldn't be completed. (Com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityProviderErrorDomain error 0.)`. I've noticed that different actions can result in different error codes, but I'd like to make the error messages more descriptive so that my users will actually know what they did wrong.

Currently, I get the error message by checking `if task.error != nil` for the login/registration/etc. task, and if this check return true, I get the string `task.error!.localizedDescription` for the error message. I realize I could grab the error code from this string by getting the substring corresponding to the 1 digit code, but this seems like a really terrible long-term solution. At the very least, I would like to get the error code as an integer, or preferably get a description of the error that will make sense to the average user. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, the Swift low level details are a bit less refined than some of the other SDKs (including Objective C). Something like this might be the best way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Made a helper that leverages @cornr answer:

```swift
extension Error {
    /// Returns a custom description for the error if available, otherwise `localizedDescription`
    var customDescription: String {
        let ns = self as NSError

        // AWS Errors
        if ns.domain == AWSCognitoIdentityProviderErrorDomain, let code = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderErrorType(rawValue: ns.code) {
            switch code {
            case .invalidParameter: return "Invalid user / password"
            case .invalidPassword: return "Invalid password."
            case .notAuthorized: return "Not authorized."
            case .userNotConfirmed: return "User not confirmed."
            case .passwordResetRequired: return "Password reset required."
            default: return "AWS Cognito Error: \(code.rawValue)"
            }
        }
        return localizedDescription
    }
}
```

Didn't fill them all in, just those that I was running into.  Feel free to edit with more.  Calling `error.customDescription` on any error will return either an improved string or the localizedDescription.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `AWSCognitoIdentityProviderErrorType` Enum (see AWSCognitoIdentityProviderModel.h).
Its rawValues represent the ErrorCodes in the `NSErrors` with the `AWSCognitoIdentityProviderErrorDomain`.